# Makefile does not create multiple txt-files using touch

Tags: makefile

I'm new to makefiles and trying to create multiple files at once by using a makefile containing `touch file-{1..10}.txt`. This doesn't work as expected as it creates a file called `file-{1..10}.txt` instead of creating the files `file-1.txt` through `file-10.txt`.

This is the code of the makefile:

```
   .DEFAULT_GOAL := generate

say_hello:
    @echo "Hello World"

generate:
    @echo "Creating empty text files..."
    touch file-{1..10}.txt

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm *.txt
```

When entering `make` into the terminal, it prints

```
Creating empty text files...
touch file-{1..10}.txt
```

and creates the file `file-{1..10}.txt`.
Entering `touch file-{1..10}.txt` into the terminal creates `file-1.txt` through `file-10.txt` as usual.

Comment: I do not reproduce the behavior you describe on my system.  On what OS are you seeing it, with which Make and shell implementation?

Comment: I am using `bash` on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and GNU Make 4.1

Comment: I just wanna say, this is from https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The POSIX standard requires that `make` always invoke the shell `/bin/sh`.  It will never invoke the user's preferred shell (think what a disaster of non-portability *that* would be!)

Brace expansion such as you want is not part of the POSIX definition of `sh`.  It's an add-on feature provided by `bash` and some other shells.  On systems where `/bin/sh` is a link to bash, such as MacOS and Red Hat-based systems, brace expansion will work in makefiles.

On systems where `/bin/sh` is a link to a POSIX-compliant shell like `dash`, such as Ubuntu, trying to use non-POSIX features in your makefile recipes will not work.

You can either write out the touch operation, or you can add:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

to your makefile to force make to invoke `bash`.  Just be aware that your makefile is now no longer portable to systems that don't have `/bin/bash` installed.

Comment: I considered that, but in fact my bash performs sequence expansion even when invoked as `/bin/sh`.  But of course, that may be correlated with the fact that I do not reproduce the OP's failure behavior.

Comment: Yes it does.  That's what I said.  If you use bash, even invoked as /bin/sh, you still get advanced features.  On other systems, `/bin/sh` is _NOT_ bash.  On Ubuntu systems for example, `/bin/sh` is dash which is specifically written to be a small, fast shell that implements only POSIX features.  On those systems, `/bin/sh` will not support brace expansion.